# Access Violation when duplicating token

Tags: c++, winapi, process

Below code generates:

> Unhandled exception at 0x749ab763 in MyProgram1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00d4eb38.

```
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = {0};
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    STARTUPINFO si = {0};
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    //si.cbReserved2 = sizeof(si);
    si.lpDesktop = L"winsta0\\default";

    CreateProcessAsUser(hUserTokenDup, NULL, L"Setup.exe", &sa, &sa, false, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &procinfo);
```

Is there anything wrong with the code? Please help

Comment: You're passing a const string to a non-const parameter (the third parameter is inout).

Comment: thanks avakar, its not showing error anymore. However the process setup.exe is not starting, there is no window and the Process in task manager does not show it. Do you know why?

Comment: @JohnKenedy, what does `GetLastError()` report?

Comment: I checked it reports 5 access denied. Then I try to setdebugprivilege using AdjustTokenPrivileges but it returns 1300 which is ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED. Then I get Token information and it returns 3 which the current process does not have TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES access. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`CreateProcessAsUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), referring to the third parameter:

> The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessAsUserW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, **this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string)**. If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.

Change to:

```
WCHAR exeName[] = L"Setup.exe";
```

and pass `exeName` as the third parameter instead.